# nx monorepo node_modules too big

Tags: angular, typescript, nest, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I have a monorepo project containing an Angular/Ionic project and two Nest projects. My issue is that when trying to deploy the Nest projects to lambda, the node_modules file is too large. This is largely due to the fact that all the Ionic dependencies are getting shipped along with it. My question is, is there a way to segment how node_modules installs within an nx monorepo project, so that I can exclude certain dependencies per project?

Comment: I think the idea is to never actually ship node_modules. You only ship src and package.json and let your build process build (and do the npm i) in your build pipeline.

Comment: You have to exclude the `node_modules` from the shipped code. The dependencies are listed in your global package.json only. There is no need to ship `node_modules` along your end project files

Answer (score 0):

Activate `"generatePackageJson"` build option in the `project.json` file of your Nest project. When setting `"generatePackageJson"` to true, you will end up with a minimal `package.json` file in the `dist` folder after you have ran the production build of your Nest App. It will drop all dependencies which are not part of your Nest App (like the Ionic stuff).

More info: https://nx.dev/packages/node/executors/webpack#generatepackagejson

**project.json**

```
{
    ...
    "projectType": "application",
    "targets": {
      "build": {
        "executor": "@nrwl/webpack:webpack",
        "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
        ...
        "configurations": {
          "production": {
            ...
            "generatePackageJson": true,
            ...
          }
        }
      },
      ...
}
```